# SQLServerException: The conversion from timestamp to TIMESTAMP is unsupported.

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

Recently made some database changes and something is messed up with the hibernate mapping.

**Hibernate Mapping:**

```
<class name="Member" table="MEMBER">
   <property name="lastLoginDate" column="last_login_date" type="calendar"/>
   ...other fields
</class>
```

**Member Model Object:**

```
public class MemberBean{
    private Calendar lastLoginDate;
    ... rest of class
}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
SEVERE: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:859)
        at com.pp.controller.dao.impl.OrganizationDaoImpl.getMember(OrganizationDaoImpl.java:83)
        at com.pp.controller.dao.impl.OrganizationDaoImpl.login(OrganizationDaoImpl.java:26)
        at com.pp.controller.MemberBean.doNavigation(MemberBean.java:300)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from timestamp to TIMESTAMP is unsupported.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DataTypes.throwConversionError(DataTypes.java:1117)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:2419)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:176)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:113)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1981)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1966)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getTimestamp(SQLServerResultSet.java:2376)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:330)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2265)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
        ... 54 more
```

Comment: SQL Server "timestamp" datatype is mapped to java "byte" datatype. How is your Calendar type defined? Try changing from java.sql.TimeStamp to byte[]

Answer (score 7):

Did you create your table with a TIMESTAMP data type instead of DATETIME? TIMESTAMP is a poorly-named type that is aliased by ROWVERSION and is used for concurrency - has very little to do with date or time.

- [How do I get date/time information from a TIMESTAMP column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154742/61305)