# SQL Server timestamp error 800a01f4

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Here is what I am trying:

```
sSQL = "INSERT into users (firstName, lastName, email, password, zip, country, company, industry, revenue, timestamp) 
        VALUES('" & fname & "','" & lName & "','" & email & "','" & password & "','" & zip & "','" & country & "','" & company & "','" & industry & "','" & revenue & "','" & CURRENT_TIMESTAMP & "')"
```

Error Message:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4'
>   Variable is undefined: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
>   /register.asp, line 24

I tried DEFAULT as the timestamp, didn't work though.

Comment: This will produce very hackable code by [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Why do you think so? And how do I fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if I set firstName = `") Values('blah') GO DELETE * FROM users GO --"`.  I just deleted all the users in your table.  Here is a small tid bit from microsoft about how to prevent [Sql Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much! Will go through it!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149848/classic-asp-sql-injection-protection) StackOverflow question. Lot of information on SQL injection.

Comment: FYI the TIMESTAMP data type has nothing to do with date or time. In addition to the syntax issues pointed out by others, you should change your column to be DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262426/sql-server-cannot-insert-an-explicit-value-into-a-timestamp-column)

Answer (score 3):

do this

```
... revenue & "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` should be part of your sql query. It is not a variable in your code.

EDIT: To make it work you should change the data type of your `timestamp` column to `datetime`.

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me the following error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e2f'

Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

/register.asp, line 37 

So I replaced CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with DEFAULT, and it worked. But when I checked the database, the value was something like this: 0x0000007D5
How do I get a readable timestamp?

Comment: what db engine are you using?

Comment: Try `getdate()` this is a build in function, that returns the current DATETIME.

Comment: @rdesai: See my update. You need to change the data type of timestamp column to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comments to one of the other answers, your fundamental problems is trying to insert into a timestamp column.  Timestamp colums can not be INSERTed or UPDATEd  Timestamp is not actually a date or time value, instead it is a row version column, handled by the db engine.  You can compare against it to avoid concurrency issues.

Leave it out of your column list and it should work.

That said, you should be using sql parameters, instead of string concatenation to create your sql commands.

Comment: This really should be a comment since it doesn't attempt to answer the question. Good point though.

Comment: @JohnFx: it did answer the question, but based upon a comment he made to another answer.  I expanded my answer to make it clearer : it's not working because you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try making `Timestamp` = `[TimeStamp]` instead, you might get issues when using this field name.