# Multiple timestamp columns in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I need to create a table in SQL Server 2000.

```
create table TABLE (
        DBID_ bigint not null,
        CLASS_ varchar(255) not null,
        DBVERSION_ integer not null,
        HPROCI_ bigint,
        TYPE_ varchar(255),
        EXECUTION_ varchar(255),
        ACTIVITY_NAME_ varchar(255),
        START_ timestamp,
        END_ timestamp,
        DURATION_ bigint,
        TRANSITION_ varchar(255),
        NEXTIDX_ integer,
        HTASK_ bigint,
        primary key (DBID_)
    );
```

An error occurs when I run it.

> *A table can only have one timestamp column. Because table `TABLE`
>   already has one, the column `END_` cannot be added.*

What is the best alternative for `timestamp` for SQL Server? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column

Answer (score 49):

A `timestamp` is not a datetime datatype as the name suggests. It is an internal value that is *relative* to the server's clock, but an actual time cannot be derived from it's value. It is simply used to evaluate whether a row has been updated, and thus a table can only have one column of this type. The `timestamp` syntax is actually deprecated and is now named [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) which makes a lot more sense.

Given your column names (Start, End) I assume you are trying to store actual timestamps, and should instead be using `datetime` as your datatype.

Comment: Gets lot of people when the come to Sql server from another DBMS this one. Fancy assuming timestamp was stamping the time on the record, just silly isn't it. :(

Comment: Nathan - Than you for your response.

Answer (score 4):

In Sql Server `timestamp` is a data type and it's not a time.
It's basically a way of versioning a record and it's used for optimistic locking in a disconnected database model
When you load up the record, you pick up the timestamp column. You only write it back if the value in the timestamp column is the same, as that means no one else has changed it since you got it.

If you want a real `datetime` value, add a datetime either not null, or with a default of `GetDate()` and remember to update every update.