# Converting timestamp to proper format

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get date/time information from a TIMESTAMP column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column)

I exported a database from SQL Server. It had a field of timestamp which is giving me value something like 00000000004285D1. How can I convert it into simple date format on MySQL. I am trying to display it on a website using PHP. Previous database was linked to the site with ASP.NET and SQL Server.

I want to convert this timestamp from 00000000004285D1 to something like 2012-09-25 10:15:23

or some other readable format.

Thanx in advance. :)

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, timestamp is not a datetime.  It is a synonym for [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx), an 8-byte binary number generally used for version-stamping table rows, often for concurrency checking.  As such, it will not make sense to turn this into a datetime in the target system.

Timestamp is arguably a confusing name for this datatype.  You can find a helpful discussion [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types).