# SQL Server INSERT timestamp inserting something else

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get date/time information from a TIMESTAMP column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column)
>   [How to convert SQL Server’s timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

I am trying to execute a simple query that inserts a timestamp. The query runs with no problems but this is what is inserted into the column rather than the current time:

```
0x00000000000007D2
```

This is the query:

```
 INSERT INTO auctions (title, description, finish_date) 
 VALUES ('Some title', 'Some description', '05/03/2003 11:15:45')
```

From what I've read `Timestamp` has been deprecated by something called `Rowversion` but I can't find such a data type in the management studio.

The auctions table:

- `auction_id - bigint`
- `title - nvarchar(MAX)`
- `description - nvarchar(MAX)`
- `start_date - timestamp`
- `finish_date - datetime`

Comment: [See my answer to this previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format/8119407#8119407) - `TIMESTAMP` has **nothing to do** with a date and/or time - it's just a numerical, system-increased **row version** number....

Comment: Another piece of advice: don't just use `nvarchar(max)` for everything. Put some thought into what max length your title and description will **really** be - 1 billion characters - each - REALLY!?!? See [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) - use the `(MAX)` types **sparingly** - only when you **REALLY** must store more than 4'000 Unicode characters.

Comment: Oh yeah this was just for testing purposes, it's always good to know the max. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the Timestamp type to store dates.

The timestamp is basically a counter of insert and update operations done within a single database, so it is local to a given database and has no real time value.

To conform with your insert statement, you should use a DateTime instead - both for your `start_date` and for your `finish_date`.

See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I thought I could use Timestamp to insert the current time?

Comment: Nope. Bizarrely, the timestamp datatype in SQL Server has no real concept of time as such. Only as time relative to specific operations done within the database.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, seems I'm getting confused with TIMESTAMP from MySQL