# Storing and comparing the date and time from SQL Server to .NET when application is used in different time zones

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, datetime

This question has no doubt been covered already but I am having trouble knowing what to search for to find an answer.

I have a .NET MVC website that is used in different countries and time zones and currently I take the .NET `DateTime.UtcNow` as the last amended date of a form and store it in a `[datetime]` field in a SQL Server 2008 database when a record is inserted/updated.

I wanted to be able to keep a log of when a user initially opened the "edit" form and then compare this to the last amended date in the database, so the user can be made aware of any further changes that occurred while they were changing the form.

I don't know if these are the relevant types to be using.

What is the recommended way to approach the above behaviour?

Comment: I think most people use a [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) column for optimistic concurrency, though note that this does not contain any information about *when* the last modification was made ([even though its deprecated name, `timestamp`, implies that it does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column)).

Comment: Also I'm not sure how the different time zones affect your question. Your use of UTC time seems to solve a completely different problem - your question really should be "can I use date/time for optimistic concurrency"...

Comment: My purpose was to compare the stored SQL `datetime` with the date & time of when the form was opened, which I presume would need to be a .NET `DateTime.UTCNow`. I don't believe I have the need to store any time zone specific date times in my database, this example was for optimistic concurrency like you say.. I'm not yet sure what a `rowversion` could be compared to in .NET. An alternative could be that the date & time the form is opened is stored in a log table in the database and compared that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a proactive [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) check.  You can certainly use a datetime field for this assuming that level of granularity is 'good enough'.  If you're not sure, I would recommend using an integer instead that increments with each update - no granularity problems there.

Comment: The use of an integer is a nice suggestion, thank you. That should suffice in my situation considering the size of a 32-bit signed integer. I presume based on your comments that UtcNow was the correct choice in this situation and datetime is enough to store that correctly? considering how it's not ISO-8601 compliant from what this says http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx.

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern about ISO-8601 is for this purpose.  You will be using this field for an internal mechanism that shouldn't require conforming to an arbitrary external-facing standard.  And although it's not inherently compliant - you can always format a datetime to conform with ISO-8601 if you need to.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I wasn't incorrectly storing the date & time in SQL.

Comment: UTC is the 'most correct' way to store datetimes that need comparison.  How the database stores this internally shouldn't matter for you as long as it treats it as such and your adapter can recreate it just as you passed it in.