# Retrieve DateTime of RowVersion from transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

Is it possible to get the datetime associated with a particular RowVersion number from the the transaction log? I'm hopeful because it seems to track which RowVersions are active so it's got to be in there, right?

The reason I ask is that I've got an incremental load that reads uptil `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` and an alert set to fire if that's been lagging behind `@@DBTS` too many consecutive times.

I'd like the alert email to use that paralysed `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` to pinpoint when the freeze happened and just how out of sync the destination DB has become.

Comment: [`ROWVERSION` is a simple incrementer that doesn't know anything about date or time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column).

Comment: I know but the transaction log knows about the datetime of each transaction and i see no reason it wouldn't also know the rowversion of each. If so, that link must be getable somehow, right?

Comment: Ah, thank you for the link Aaron! I didn't originally realise it was one, just thought you'd formatted for emphasis. The "ruler" table idea in there is great and gives me faith that there isn't some easy lookup function I'm missing.