# DATETIME or timestamp which i should prefer?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I am using SQL Server 2008. The server is in india. I want to store the users login and logout time. I can easily do that in SQL Server.

Now we have clients/admins from different countries who will check those login/logout time. They want these times in their respective time zone.

One more scenario is my clients travel from one country to another country, so the log time should be automatically updated as per the timezone.

So my understanding is I have to store the timezone info along with datetime for clients. So that I can use `TimeZoneInfo::ConvertTime` method to convert to different time zones.

I can give my clients an option to save their timezone while registration.

But my doubt is if my client changes his country do they need to change their timezone manually or is there any way i can automatically detect timezone. Is it feasible to check for the system timezone?

Or anyway storing timestamp can help me?

Comment: Store the data in UTC using datetime (or datetime2 depending on precision). It is much easier to convert UTC to <any time zone> for display than to convert <some other time zone> to <yet another time zone> for display. DateTimeOffset has some of this but not all; for example, it doesn't understand DST. The timestamp data type was just a poor naming choice and [has absolutely nothing to do with date or time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154742/how-do-i-get-date-time-information-from-a-timestamp-column).

Comment: I have a three-part series on this over on MSSQLTips.com - look under my [author profile](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/49/aaron-bertrand/) at the three posts under the "Dates" category.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: what is the best way to get the clients timezone?

Comment: If they log into your system you can just ask for it once, then you have it. If you want to rely on the browser, you can get it from the client side (and JavaScript can help with transitions to/from UTC rather than saddling SQL Server with that).

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetimeoffset`. My company has operations all over Europe, a few Asian countries, and North America. Code your application so that it passes along the timezone setting of the current computer to the database. When a user travels, Windows can update the timezone information as it detects the geographical location of the user. I never had to worry about DST that way (imagine the fun dealing with daylight savings time in 2 continents).

Since the timezone info is stored, I can convert it to any timezone I want. Or the application reading the data can do that, using the local computer timezone.