# How to set timestamp on update event in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

While creating a table or alter the table using the below command getting the below error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

Please help me - how to set on update timestamp?

```
create table my_table 
(
    index1 char(32) not null primary key,
    title varchar(50),
    my_timestamp timestamp not null 
         default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);
```

Comment: `timestamp` is poorly named, and isn't what you think it is. See [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154742/61305). You need a `datetime` or `datetime2` column to capture updates (and a separate column if you want to separate creation from later updates). And you'll need a trigger to populate it...

Answer (score 1):

The datatype `Timestamp` is auto generated by SQL Server it self, you cannot specify a default constraint on it.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`Timestamp` is deprecated and rowversion should be used.

Comment: it is a binary format like ... 0x00000000000007D4

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server is ***NOT***  something to store date & time values. It's an internal, binary counter - aptly renamed `ROWVERSION` by now.

If you need to store date and time, use `DATEITME2(n)` instead.

```
create table my_table 
(
    index1 char(32) not null primary key,
    title varchar(50),
    my_timestamp datetim2(3) not null 
);
```

Unfortunately, to get the "last date & time row was modified" functionality, you'll need to use a trigger - you cannot do this using a `DEFAULT` constraint...